# Convert multiple cells of a column into single cell in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, row, converters, vba

I want to Select Some cells of A column and convert those into one single cell on a column And add The , or / Character between of every cells data.

For example Please see my picture.
I Have selected some cells in a column and want to convert or merge those to single cell with / separated cells data.

Picture:

[image: Image - click here]

I am very amateur in Excel. Please give me a guidance for step by step convert.

Comment: Do you actually need VBA? You can just concat with a formula (`=B2&","&B3&","&B4`)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2016 you can use a new function called Textjoin() with the syntax

```
=Textjoin(delimiter, ignore empty text, range to join)
```

From your screenshot it seems that you want to join the text from rows 12 to 15 in each column, so the formula would be

```
=Textjoin("/",true,B12:B15)
```

Copy that formula to the right.

In earlier versions of Excel you can use

```
=B12&"/"&B13&"/"&B14&"/"&B15
```

and copy to the right.

By the way, it would make our task of helping you a little bit easier if the sample screenshot shows English instead of Arabic, because with Arabic, most of us will be forced to compare the pictorials, since most of us can't read Arabic as easily as English.

Comment: My rows is too many ! this way is not suitable for me.Is any way for automatic convert specified column of rows with equal first column? For example if first column of this file be equal for some rows , So some specified column of thats rows (with equal first column value) convert into one cell and I will have one row for every user..is any way?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Edit your question and post a screenshot that is easier for English speaking people to read, then explain in context.